# How to properly shorten deadline in context

Tags: go

I am aware that this is not the proper use of a context package, but I am using gopher-lua and I am not able to find better solution.

I am calling a function with a context parameter (lua.NewState with the context set) and I am properly canceling the context.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), deadline)
defer cancel()
Foo(ctx, parameters)
```

But somewhere **inside** the function *Foo* in another subfunction *Poo* I need to cut the deadline a little bit. I am using:

```
func Poo(l *lua.LState, timeout time.Duration) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(l.Context(), timeout)
    l.SetContext(ctx)
}
```

However, I am not sure if I have to call the cancel function from function *Poo* to avoid a memory leak. In current code I am discarding the cancel, because the parent cancel is always called and propagated downwards. Go vet complains about discarding the cancel, but it probably misses the point.

Is my idea good enough or should I find better solution?

Comment: Vet is yelling because it can't verify that the parent cancel occurs.  Realistically, there's no reason to discard the cancel rather than simply deferring it.  Just because the parent cancel is _currently_ being called doesn't mean that will always be the case, or something else won't break it.  It's always good practice to defer your cancels, even if you know they'll always be canceled, because it doesn't really cost you anything, and it can save debugging and headache later.  Most memory leaks come from changes with unexpected side effects elsewhere.

Comment: I cannot defer the cancel in the function Poo because it immediately quit the parent function Foo. I can save the cancel into a package variable and call it from the outside function later or do some other event syncing, but if it is not necessary I will prefer discarding the cancel function.

Comment: You can do the same thing `WithTimeout` does and return the cancel function from `Poo`, and let `Poo`'s caller defer it.

Comment: Canceling a child context does not cancel the parent context.  Cancelations propagate downward, not upward: https://play.golang.org/p/hiBFTT04yVJ.  If you cancel in Foo, Poo will exit early.  If you cancel in Poo, Foo is unaffected.

Comment: Ahhh, you're directly *altering* the context in your `l` variable, rather than retaining a different copy.  Problematic design.

Comment: Yes, it is problematic design, but otherwise gopher-lua is an outstanding package, so I have to deal with it. I need to modify timeout directly from lua script (probably not so common requirement).